# What is intermittently breaking my short block of VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352270/check-with-vba-if-an-element-exists-on-the-page) I have fixed the object checker. Sometimes the code will run fine for 10 entries, getting them all correct, sometimes it'll run for five. Sometimes it'll get the entries wrong.

It always tends to fail on the getting innertext of the element. When it gets the Y/N result wrong, I don't know at all what's causing that.

Please help! It's driving me mad. I've error checked at every stage over and again.

```
Sub LetsAutomateIE()

Dim barcode As String
Dim rowe As Integer
Dim document As HTMLDocument
Dim Element As HTMLDivElement
Dim text As String
Dim pos As Integer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
rowe = 2

While Not IsEmpty(Cells(rowe, 2))
    barcode = Cells(rowe, "B").Value
    pos = 0
    text = ""
    Set document = Nothing

    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .navigate2 "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=" & barcode
        Do Until ie.readyState = 4
        Loop
    End With

    Set document = ie.document

    If IsObject(document.getElementById("result_0")) = False Then GoTo Here

    text = document.getElementById("result_0").innerText
    If InStr(text, "STEELBOOK") Or InStr(text, "Steelbook") Or InStr(text, "Steel book") <> 0 Then pos = 1

    If pos <> 0 Then Cells(rowe, 4) = "Y" Else Cells(rowe, 4) = "N"

    Here:

    rowe = rowe + 1
Wend
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is a selection of sample barcodes I was working with. I've never managed to get through these successfully.

```
5030305517076
5030305517816
5060223767925
5060223767949
5060223767956
5060223767970
5060223767994
8717418358563
8717418365851
```

Thank you so much,

Sam

Comment: Put `DoEvents` into the waiting loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is the fact that for some barcodes no results are found.
If you would test your code with `IE.Visible = true` then you will see text like this:

> Your search "5060223767949" did not match any products.

Another problem is the condition `IsObject(document.getElementById("result_0")) = False`. This doesn't work well, because `IsObject(Nothing)` returns `true`. Better would be to use `If <variable-name> Is Nothing Then ...`.

The complete code. HTH

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub LetsAutomateIE()
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim barcode As String
    Dim rowe As Integer
    Dim document As HTMLDocument
    Dim Element As HTMLDivElement
    Dim result01 As HTMLListElement
    Dim noResults As HTMLHeaderElement
    Dim text As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim url As String

    rowe = 2
    url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(rowe, 2))
        barcode = Cells(rowe, "B").Value
        pos = 0
        text = ""

        IE.Navigate url & barcode

        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set document = IE.document
        Set result01 = document.getElementById("result_0")

        If result01 Is Nothing Then
            Set noResults = document.getElementById("noResultsTitle")
            If Not noResults Is Nothing Then MsgBox noResults.outerText
            GoTo Here
        End If

        text = document.getElementById("result_0").innerText
        If InStr(text, "STEELBOOK") Or InStr(text, "Steelbook") Or InStr(text, "Steel book") <> 0 Then pos = 1

        If pos <> 0 Then Cells(rowe, 4) = "Y" Else Cells(rowe, 4) = "N"

Here:
        rowe = rowe + 1
    Wend

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

> I'm actually looking just to check the title of the first returned
>   product on the page...

The title is displayed with `h2` element within `li` with id `result_0`. So it is possible to limit the search just to this `li` element and search for first `h2` element.

```
' text = document.getElementById("result_0").innerText

Dim h2Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim h2 As HTMLHeadElement

Set h2Elements = result01.getElementsByTagName("h2")

If h2Elements.Length > 0 Then
    Set h2 = h2Elements.Item(0)
    text = h2.innerText
    Debug.Print text
Else
    MsgBox "Text not found"    
End If
```

> Output:

```
RED 2 Blu-ray Steelbook UK Exclusive
The Hunger Games With Mockingjay Pendant
The Hunger Games
The Hunger Games
Avengers Assemble BD Steelbook
Avengers Assemble Bonus Disc BD Retail
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help dee! I'd seen the product not found, and that's why I was trying to search to see if results_0 was there, as that frame doesn't appear (I believe) in that circumstance.

I look forward to trying your code now! Thanks again :)

Comment: One final question if anyone stumbles on this and can help: I'm actually looking just to check the title of the first returned product on the page. I'm currently searching through all text in the frame/class/I'm not sure what to call it. Is it possible to limit the search to just the title?

Comment: It did, enormously. Thanks again. :) I raise the next bit as a curiosity rather than a plea for help as you've already done so much, but currently this code generates an ie task in the task manager that grows and grows and grows and eventually causes and error when it gets too big. I'm going to look into it myself, but if you know (top of head!) why....!

Comment: On my PC the code doesn't cause any problems, iexplorer.exe process is terminated immediatelly after the IE.Quit is called in VBA code. If you debug the code can you see if the problem is in VBA code itself? Btw. is the row `rowe = rowe + 1` still there?

Comment: You're right in that the process quits correctly! I'm running the macro on 1000+ titles though. After about 200 or so the task manager looks like this (http://imgur.com/a/oQxUg) and the code throws an error. If I then quit the task and restart the macro it all works well again.

Comment: Which error exactly is thrown? Could you locate the row of VBA code which caused the error?

Comment: Hi Dee. I ran it again and waited for the error - both it and the line of code highlighted on debug are here: http://imgur.com/a/JlGzE. This was again when the ie task had hit about 1.5GB of memory. Your thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried some from [this advices](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320369)?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with `document.getElementById("result_0")` throwing an error.  My workaround was to test if the element was in the Document.Body.InnerHTML.

If you set `DebugMode` to True then the webpage with bad results is left open for further inspection.

The barcode will be marked NA if not found.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LetsAutomateIE()
    Const DebugMode As Boolean = True
    Dim barcode As String, text As String
    Dim rowe As Integer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument, liResults As HTMLLIElement
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    rowe = 2

    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(rowe, 2))
        barcode = Cells(rowe, "B").Value

        With ie
            .Visible = False
            .navigate2 "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=" & barcode
            Do Until ie.readyState = 4
            Loop
        End With

        Set doc = ie.document
        If InStr(doc.body.innerHTML, "li id=""result_0""") Then

            Set liResults = doc.getElementById("result_0")
            text = liResults.innerText
            Cells(rowe, 4) = IIf(InStr(text, "STEELBOOK") Or InStr(text, "Steelbook") Or InStr(text, "Steel book"), "Y", "N")

        Else
            Cells(rowe, 4) = "NA"
            If DebugMode Then
                ie.Visible = True
                Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            End If
        End If
        rowe = rowe + 1
    Wend

    ie.Quit

    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much Thomas :)