# Checking if HTML elements exists after a input with VBA does not work correctly using html.getElementById()

Tags: vba

I am pretty new to VBA and don't have much experience with it.
I have a excel sheet with more then 500 commands for which I want to test if the syntax of the command is correct. To do so I thought about using VBA to automate this process.

For the start I went with just one command to see if it could work, but it does not. My code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

URL = "https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html"

IE.Navigate URL

While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

IE.Document.getElementById("regex").Value = "\b(Yes"
IE.Document.getElementById("input").Value = "Yaes"
IE.Document.getElementById("matchesButton").Click

While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Set html = IE.Document

If IsNull(html.getElementById("output")) Then
    Worksheets(12).Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If


Set IE = Nothing
```

The input "\b(Yes" should be with syntax errors, so there should be this HTML code:

```
<div id="output" class="form-wrapper" style="margin-top:20px;padding-left:20px;">
```

But checking this id="ouptut" does not work, with this error there should no <div id="output" be and therefore IsNull(html.getElementById("output")) should return a Null/True and the excel cell should be marked red.

Can anyone please help me out with my logic error in the code? I tried already hours and should be simple, but I was not able to find a solution via google.

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352270/check-with-vba-if-an-element-exists-on-the-page) here, you need to check if the object exists rather than if the element is null.

Create the object first

```
set Element = html.getElementByID("output")
```

Then run your check to see if the object exists

```
if isObject(Element) then
```

Try that.

Comment: Thank you. I still get the error: run time error '1004' Application defined or object defined error.